# how to detect if string is true or false

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, evaluate

Ive recently been advised we appear to have a bug in a script we put together many years ago.

Basically its for an import utility that reads in quite a lot of data.

We basically leverage the java POI utliity to read in a spreadsheet, and we are appearing to have issue with true false statements.

```
<cfif Evaluate("GetobjSheet.Query.#sysArray[26][5]#")>1<cfelse>0</cfif>
```

This appears to work correctly when the string true or false is present, but occasionally we find people are forgetting to enter in the value.

is there a function within Coldfusion that will automatically treat empty strings or strings that dont validate to true automatically as false ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'd simply do `<cfif len(GetobjSheet.Query[sysArray[26][5]]) AND GetobjSheet.Query[sysArray[26][5]]>1<cfelse>0</cfif>`  - also don't use `evaluate()` - it's generally frowned upon these days in CF

Comment: You should make that an answer, @duncan. And when you say "these days", you mean "the last decade or so, more than half of ColdFusion's lifetime", right? And in this case, I doubt it was ever needed, or the appropriate way of writing this code.

Comment: It is not so much that `evaluate()` is frowned upon, there are legitimate use cases for it, but, in this case, it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply do

```
<cfif len(GetobjSheet.Query[sysArray[26][5]]) AND GetobjSheet.Query[sysArray[26][5]]>
1
<cfelse>
0
</cfif>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the part starting with "and"?

Comment: @DanBracuk The condition is only true if the expression resolves to a boolean true value. However - according to the OP - it could have one of three states: true, false or null (well: empty string in this case).